# zsh /home/kaffe/.aliases:13: parse error near `|'

Tags: zshrc

I wrote a massive one-liner as a tool to check some logs at work which I wanted to break up and comment, so I could understand it at a later date. When I was done breaking it all up, I bumped into this error:

> /home/kaffe/.aliases:13: parse error near `|'

```
11 mlog () {
12     cat /home/kaffe/progs/muse/nxaa* \                                     # Look in all muse logs
13     | grep "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')\|$(date --date '-1 days' +'%Y-%m-%d')" \   # Dynamic search for date - today and yesterday
14     | sed -e 's/ com.*(): / /; \                                           # Start sed, remove irrelevant information
15     s/;/ /;s/;/ /; \                                                       # Remove first two instances of semi-colon in every line
16     s/, severity../ /; \                                                   # Globally remove mention of severity level
17     s/.*New alarm:/    New: &/g; \                                         # If "New alarm:" exists, add "New:" to beginning of line
18     s/ New alarm: / /g1; \                                                 # Globally remove "New alarm:" from line
19     s/.*Alarm cleared:/Cleared: &/g; \                                     # If "Alarm cleared:" exists, add "Cleared:" to beginning
20     s/ Alarm cleared: / /g1; \                                             # Globally remove "Alarm cleared:" from line
21     s/.*Alarm changed:/Changed: &/g; \                                     # If "Alarm changed:" exists, add "Changed:" to beginning
22     s/ Alarm changed: / /g1' \                                             # Globally remove "Alarm changed:" from line
23     -e ''/    New:/s//$(printf "\033[31mNew:\033[0m")/g'' \                # Color "New:" red
24     -e ''/Cleared:/s//$(printf "\033[32mCleared:\033[0m")/g'' \            # Color "Cleared:" green
25     -e ''/Changed:/s//$(printf "\033[33mChanged:\033[0m")/g'' \            # Color "Changed:" yellow
26     | sort -k1.24 \                                                        # Sort from 14th character (date)
27     | egrep -i $1                                                          # Insert custom search pattern, allow regexp, case insensitive
28 }
```

The function seems to work as intended, though. I just wish to understand why there is an error and my abysmal zsh-fu restricts me from figuring it out. Knowing what causes this would probably help me in future zsh endeavors.

Thanks in advance for any contribution.

OS and zsh versions:

```
$ uname -a
Linux kaffe-noc 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ zsh --version
zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have those comments in real code ?
You can not have anything after `\` but a newline for line continuation.

`man bash`

> A  non-quoted  backslash  ()  is the escape character.  It preserves
>   the literal value of the next character that follows, with the
>   exception of .  If a \ pair appears, and the
>   backslash is not itself quoted, the \ is treated as a line
>   continuation (that is, it is removed from the input stream and
>   effectively ignored).

Comment: Despite knowing this, I took a left turn somewhere and thought it would work anyway. It all adds up to a prolonged moment of "derp".

Thanks for the reply, it's all a-ok now. :)